# Conversion of arrays using map or any other methods - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This is my json object:

```
{
   id: 3,
   cno: 103,
   username: 'basha',
   name: 'New Complaint',
   desc: 'Need bag',
   storeId: [ 5, 1 ]
}
```

I want my expected output like this:

```
[
  {id: 3,cno: 103,username: 'basha',name: 'New Complaint',desc: 'Need bag',storeId:5},
  {id: 3,cno: 103,username: 'basha',name: 'New Complaint',desc: 'Need bag',storeId:1}
]
```

Comment: I tried using map, but i dont get! if you post some piece of code, i will get and practice with that.

Comment: If you post your code, we would know where you are stuck and how far you need to go. Just putting input and output format is requirement. We all have managers for that. SO is for problem statements. Please share your code.

Comment: Ok sure. i will share

Comment: only sortedID is an array or all can ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right to choose `.map`. Issue is, you are trying to update an object and objects are passed using reference. So all the objects will hold same id. You will have to create a copy so that you do not override value. You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for that.

```js
var data = {
   id: 3,
   cno: 103,
   username: 'basha',
   name: 'New Complaint',
   desc: 'Need bag',
   storeId: [ 5, 1 ]
};

var result = data.storeId.map(function(id){
  return Object.assign({}, data, {storeId: id});
});
console.log(result)
```

If you are not comfortable using ES6 features, you can check following: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` on the array `storeId` and return a new object which has current value as the value of `storeId`.

```js
var obj = {
   id: 3,
   cno: 103,
   username: 'basha',
   name: 'New Complaint',
   desc: 'Need bag',
   storeId: [ 5, 1 ]
};

var data = obj.storeId.map(el => {
  let newObject = Object.assign({}, obj);
  newObject.storeId = el;
  return newObject;
})

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` with spread syntax to create an object with all the existing property and individual `storeId`.

```js
var obj = {id: 3,cno: 103,username: 'basha',name: 'New Complaint',desc: 'Need bag',storeId: [ 5, 1 ]}
    result = obj.storeId.map(storeId => ({...obj, storeId}) )
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
   id: 3,
   cno: 103,
   username: 'basha',
   name: 'New Complaint',
   desc: 'Need bag',
   storeId: [ 5, 1 ]
}


var finalData = data.storeId.map(x => {
  return({
     id: data.id,
     cno: data.cno,
     username: data.username,
     name: data.name,
     desc: data.desc,
     storeId: x
  })
});

console.log(finalData);
```

I tried this now i got this answer correctly, is this good approach?

Comment: *is this good approach?* Yes. Since you are using ES6 features, you can check other answers suggesting `Object.assign`.

Comment: Yea definitely, nothing wrong here.. But you can get rid of the hassle of creating the whole object again by using `Object.assign()` and the suggested approach will be more robust in case certain object miss a key or gets a new key.